# Using Spring Security SAML Siteminder

Tags: spring-security, saml, siteminder

I'm trying to integrate siteminder with Spring Security.
Users already connected to Windows (Domain Authentification) can access to the WebApplication ( Tomcat - RHEL ) with the current Windows username, roles are managed by the WebApp it self.
it is possible ? it there any example that might help me to kick off this project

i used to read about Spring Security but i can't figure out how to implement this configuration.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/chapter-quick-start.html

Answer (score 0):

We are in the process of rewriting Spring Security SAML for a better user experience.

In the meantime, you can explore our milestone release `2.0.0.M24` being the latest.

Gradle URL

```
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
        ...
    }
```

Import the dependency

```
compile "org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-saml2-core:2.0.0.M24")
```

There is a [sample project available](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/blob/ca29a44d4777425e9553d8e97ef960ef1b95d935/samples/boot/simple-service-provider/src/main/resources/application.yml#L23-L168)`[1]` if you want to try it out. It's part of the core repository.

A github contributor has also created a [separate sample and guide](https://github.com/Endeios/samlv2app)

This should get you started.

The future will look something like this *(not yet released)*:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            //application security
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            //saml security
            .apply(
                SamlServiceProviderConfigurer.saml2Login()
            )
        ;
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Bean
    protected ServiceProviderConfigurationResolver configurationResolver() {
        return fromConfiguration(
            config -> config
                .keys(
                    KeyData.builder()
                        .id("sp-signing-key")
                        .privateKey(privateKey)
                        .certificate(certificate)
                        .passphrase("sppassword")
                        .build()
                )
                .providers(
                    ExternalIdentityProviderConfiguration.builder()
                        .alias("simplesamlphp")
                        .metadata("http://simplesaml-for-spring-saml.cfapps.io/saml2/idp/metadata.php")
                        .build()
                )
        );
    }

    private String privateKey = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n" +
        "Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED\n" +
        "DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,7C8510E4CED17A9F\n" +
        "\n" +
        "...==\n" +
        "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
    private String certificate = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" +
        "...\n" +
        "RZ/nbTJ7VTeZOSyRoVn5XHhpuJ0B\n" +
        "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

}
```

**References:**

`[1]` https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/blob/ca29a44d4777425e9553d8e97ef960ef1b95d935/samples/boot/simple-service-provider/src/main/resources/application.yml#L23-L168

`[2]` https://github.com/Endeios/samlv2app